# ASP.Net Entity Framework Repository & Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, repository

My scenario:

This is an ASP.NET 4.0 web app programmed via C#

I implement a repository pattern. My repositorys all share the same `ObjectContext`, which is stored in httpContext.Items. Each repository creates a new `ObjectSet` of type E. Heres some code from my repository:

```
public class Repository<E> : IRepository<E>, IDisposable
    where E : class
{
    private DataModelContainer _context = ContextHelper<DataModelContainer>.GetCurrentContext();
    private IObjectSet<E> _objectSet;
    private IObjectSet<E> objectSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_objectSet == null)
            {
                _objectSet = this._context.CreateObjectSet<E>();
            }
            return _objectSet;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<E> GetQuery()
    {
        return objectSet;
    }
```

Lets say I have 2 repositorys, 1 for states and 1 for countrys and want to create a linq query against both. Note that I use POCO classes with the entity framework. State and Country are 2 of these POCO classes.

```
Repository stateRepo = new Repository<State>();
Repository countryRepo = new Repository<Country>();

IEnumerable<State> states = (from s in _stateRepo.GetQuery()
                             join c in _countryRepo.GetQuery() on s.countryID equals c.countryID
                             select s).ToList();
Debug.WriteLine(states.First().Country.country)
```

essentially, I want to retrieve the state and the related country entity. The query only returns the state data... and I get a null argument exception on the `Debug.WriteLine`

LazyLoading is disabled in my .edmx... thats the way I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a join without retrieving anything from it. There are multiple solutions to your problem:

- Use `Include` to load the dependent entities: `from s in ((ObjectSet<State>) _stateRepo.GetQuery).Include("Country")`. The problem with this approach is that you should expose the `ObjectSet` directly rather than as a `IQueryable` if you want to avoid casting.
- Use `context.LoadProperty(states.First(), s => s.Country)` to explicitly load the Country from the database for a given state.
- Select both entities in the query: `from s in ... join c ... select new { s, c }`. You won't be able to access directly the state's `Country` property but you have it in the anonymous type.
- Enable lazy loading.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542595/entity-framework-singletonish-objectcontext-good-bad-or-overthinking for my ObjectContext.

Comment: According to http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx, HttpContext.Items works on a per-request basis. Therefore different requests should not cause race conditions with the object context.

Comment: You're right for HttpContext.Items. Removed that part from my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository implementation is very similar to mine, especially the way you are storing the ObjectContext. It works fine for me, so I don't think it's a conceptual problem.

Try using a static objectcontext (no wrapper) just to see if that fixes the problem. Perhaps there is a bug in your ContextHelper which causes your context to get disposed and recreated.

Comment: I Debug.WriteLine everytime a new ObjectContext is created and am positive its working correctly. Is lazy loading enabled in your project?

Comment: We disabled it because our application is n layer and do not want other layers to be able to run queries in that fashion

Comment: @Chris Klepeis: Sorry, I missed that bit.